# Find last record for specific user (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like `Report.last`, but instead of the last record entered, I want the last record that a specific user entered.

Comment: Can you post your model code for both your Report and User objects?

Comment: If you set up your relationships correctly, it would be something like `user.reports.last` where `user` is an instance of the `User` model. [Read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like

```
Report.where(created_by_id: user_id).last
```

where the key in the where clause is the foreign key in a reports table record to the association with the user. I'd have to know how your models associate reports with their creators to know the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this for simplicity. I also added .order(updated_at) to enforce the right ordering I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the user_id or some sort of user indicator to be able to get the last record for a specific user. You will need to post more information like the model for your users and reports. But I think you are looking for something like this:

`Report.select([:user_id, :id, 'MAX(created_at)']).group(:user_id).limit(5)`

Answer (score 0):

`user = User.where(:some_condition => "some_value").first 
user.reports.last`

This would work if user is a local variable representing an active record user and records would query its associated records and find the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have model relationship between User & Report

```
user = User.first
user.reports.order("updated_at DESC").last
```